# Docker cp not overwriting files

Tags: docker

I would like to run a few tests inside docker and therefore load my updated code inside an existing container to save on rebuilding the image all the time.

`docker cp` seems to be an ideal solution for this – but it does not seem to overwrite my existing files, here is a short test I did. I created a new file locally, copied it into my container, changed the file locally, copied it again and compared the contents of the file before and after changing on the container.

```
>> touch test123
>> docker cp test123 my-container:/
>> docker exec my-container cat /test123
(empty)
>> vi test123
(add some text on my local machine)
>> docker cp test123 my-container:/
>> docker exec my-container cat /test123
(empty)
>> vi test123
(check if the content was saved –> yes)
```

As we can see the changes have not been copied. The same happens when copying the whole folder (what I actually plan to do). The [Docker Docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/#parent-command) says: `DEST_PATH exists and is a file the destination is overwritten with the source file’s contents`, so I am wondering what I am doing wrong here.

The Docker image of the container is based on `ubuntu:16.04`.

Help is really appreciated here.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. `docker cp` overwrites the file as it should. You are missing a `docker` before your second exec line, might that be the problem? Anyway, better mount a host directory into the container than copying on every change for local development.

Comment: @SvenKoschnicke No, the `docker` command wasn't missing, that was a mistake of mine whilst copying to SO. If you can't reproduce, could it be the version (mine is `17.12.0-ce` on Mac)? I will try mounting it, but that wouldn't integrate as nicely into the development process.

Comment: I have Version 18.01.0-ce on Linux. Of course it could be a bug in your version, but I think that's unlikely. What is better with copying than mounting it directly?

Comment: did you tried to use container ID?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Docker released an update recently that fixed the issue. I ran the same procedure after updating (new version is `17.12.0-ce-mac55`) and the overwriting worked now.

It was probably an issue with macOS High Sierra and the new file system APFS. The update mentioned that it fixed an issue [*Disk/image corruption with large numbers of files*](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2625).